# How do I move diff contents of one file to another (in git)?

Tags: git, refactoring, mv

I'm having an issue upon merging to master in git.
A file that I was working on in my local branch (old.file) has been moved and renamed in master (to new.file).
After merging master into my branch I now have the new file and working changes on the old file.

How do I move changed contents of old.file into new.file?
I only want to move the 20-something changed lines of old.file into new.file and then delete old.file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Store diff/patch

You're going to need a patch/diff of what your looking to do. You can do this in multiple ways but I find the easiest way is the [following](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

`git diff <some SHAid or HEAD^ or etc...> -- old.file > changes.diff`

### Modify diff

Now we're going to want to change the diff so that it can be applied to the new.file

change the

```
---a/old.file
+++b/old.file
```

to

```
---a/new.file
+++b/new.file
```

### Apply the diff

now that the patch is going to be pointing to the correct file

`git apply changes.diff`

### Cleanup (optional)

Be sure to remove the old.file from the repo (and local file) as it is probably no longer needed.

`git rm old.file`